# Custom alignment for GeoMarkers

Tags: labeling, geography, geographics

I need to align a `GeoMarker` at the bottom left of the marker:

```
f = Framed[
   Style["Dill", FontColor -> Orange, FontSize -> 17, 
    FontFamily -> "CMU Serif Upright Italic", FontWeight -> Bold], 
   Background -> GrayLevel[0.9], RoundingRadius -> 5, 
   FrameMargins -> {{10, 10}, {5, 5}}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thickness@2], 
   ContentPadding -> False];

g = Graphics[{Orange, AbsoluteThickness[1.3], CapForm["Round"], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, .5}, {1, .5}}], 
    Inset[f, {1, .5}, ImageScaled[{0, .5}]], PointSize[0.2], 
    Point[{0, 0}]}];
```

[image]

Of course the bend in the graphics makes the positioning using `Alignment->Left` wrong:

[image]

which is exacerbated at higher zoom levels:

```
GeoGraphics[
 GeoMarker[GeoPosition[{64.147049`, -21.932949`}], g, 
  "Scale" -> Scaled[.4], "Alignment" -> Left], GeoZoomLevel -> 5, 
 ImageSize -> {200, 100}]
```

[image]

Until alignment of GeoMarkers is made more robust, ala `Inset[g, pos, opos, size, dirs]`, does anyone know of a simple workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I missed that "Alignment" can be set to `Scaled[{0, 0}]`.

```
GeoGraphics[
 GeoMarker[GeoPosition[{64.147049`, -21.932949`}], g, 
  "Scale" -> Scaled[.4], "Alignment" -> ImageScaled[{0, 0}]], 
 GeoZoomLevel -> 18, ImageSize -> {200, 100}]
```

[image]